# Spark error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sparklyr

Using Sparklyr, I'm trying to do a `spark_connect(master="yarn")`, but I'm receiving this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps
...
Error in spark_connect_gateway(gatewayAddress, gatewayPort,sessionId,   :
   Gateway in localhost:8880 did not respond
```

I have Spark version 2.4.8 and Scala version 2.12.10. I'm running on a Google DataProc cluster [using these version specs](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/versioning/dataproc-release-1.5). I'm using Sparklyr version 1.3.1.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947449/run-a-scala-code-jar-appear-nosuchmethoderrorscala-predef-refarrayops